# How to update data from local SQL Server database to online SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms, web-services

I am creating a web site which I want to show data of my local SQL Server database. My local SQL Server database is updated by other desktop application.

I have created an online SQL Server database which is used by my website. I want to update my online database with my local database in every 10 minutes.

How can I do it programatically? Or is there any way to do my task than how can I do it??

I am badly stuck at that. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Google Replication and Log Shipping. Either of them can be a solution. If you are using Sql Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups is another option for you.

Comment: I think it will work for but i have one more doubt. I want to update only those entries which are changed in my local database.i want to use it only for single table. Can i do it with That?

Comment: Yes then replication is the way to go, In replication you can explicitly select the articles(Sql Server Objects) that you want to be pushed over to secondary database from primary database. It can be one table or it can be all the tables on primary server.

Comment: OK , So do i make any application or other thing to connect them or local server data will be updated there automatically? I am asking because i am very new at it.

Comment: You application can connect to either of the databases as they will have identical data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M.Ali suggested, SQL Server Replication is your best choice. 
It's not hard to implement an SQL Server replication and I'm not going to talk too much details as there are many useful subjects on that matter.

The idea is that the local database is the publisher DB and the online one is the subscriber.(based on your requirements)

If the online one is for read only, then you can create a snapshot or a transnational replication on your local database and you can schedule at the subscriber(online Database) to pull the subscription every 10 minutes.

Comment: I think it will work for but i have one more doubt. I want to update only those entries which are changed in my local database.i want to use it only for single table. Can i do it with That?

Comment: @user3346501 you can do one table with replication. You can do that too using C# windows service which is troublesome. Based on my experience, replication is much easier.

Comment: What is the procedure to do replication from offline database to online database? Can u give me any reference or any example? Because on google i only found replication between some local databases.

Comment: @user3346501 Online or offline. It doesn't really matter as long as your both databases on the same network. They both are local(on the same network). Aren't they?

Comment: I Applied Your Procedure. But when i want to make subscriber to my online server, it is showing me error,'sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-the-server'. And i am not able to do it

Comment: yes you should type server name not the ip address when login

Comment: "Because on google i only found replication between some local databases" That's what you said indicating that your both databases are not on the same network.

Comment: Can we talk somewhere else so that comments not convert into chat. I need to talk to yu more about that topic. it will be more helpful for me

Comment: I would but not now. Have to sleep. Maybe later

Comment: Are u there? If You Are Than Can we Discuss Something About my Problem??